# How do the numbers and letters differ in hexadecimal colours?

Tags: colors, hex, visual-effects

I had a look at how hexadecimal colour codes work, for the most part, it seems pretty simple. But one thing I don't understand. If I have the code #37136F, how does the 6 and the F work together? Does this mean that the two number values are added together? So the blue value is 21? Or do they add together like: 615? If it is added together (which I feel like if the most logical way) then the maximum value you can get is 30, which gives me a range of 0-30... I feel like this isn't right, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you split the hex code into pairs of digits (so `#37136F` becomes `37`, `13`, and `6F`), and those are the values for red, green, and blue respectively. Let's focus on the blue component, `6F`.

`6F` is a two digit hexadecimal number (base 16). Just as `25` in base 10 is actually `2*10 + 5`, `6F` in hexadecimal is actually `6*16 + 15 = 111` in base 10. In general, if `X` and `Y` are hexadecimal digits (`0` through `F`), then `XY` in base 16 is `X*16 + Y`.

Note that the minimum and maximum two-digit hex numbers are `00` and `FF` respectively, which equal `0*16 + 0 = 0` and `15*16 + 15 = 255` respectively. This is why RGB values range from `0` to `255` inclusive, when written in base 10.